# Azure RemoteApp security issue

Tags: azure

I got a situation here.

I got the RemoteApp and VM image all setup and running. 
I only published Paint for user to use via the RemoteApp client.

But in fact I can access any application on the VM by open up the Paint,  File -> Open.  Which will popup a dialog for user to pick a image to open in Paint.  I can actually use this dialog to access folders and application and I was able to open windows media player from the dialog which is not being published in RemoteApp.

Could someone please advise 
Many thanks in advance.

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got an answer from Microsoft support

The behavior you described is expected. If you need to block apps from the users you need to use AppLocker or something similar.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd723678(v=ws.10).aspx

Problem solved.

Cheers